# I'm trying to fix my code, but I can't figure out how telegram parse messages

Tags: kotlin, telegram

Here is my code, it works (but not as it should), with which I can get the text of the post and 1 attached media file, but if there is more than 1 media file in the post, then I only get the last one.

I use the library, `kotlogram` almost the same as `telethon`

```
try {

var messageText = ""
    // Get most recent message
    val tl = client.messagesGetHistory(inputPeer, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
    var mess = tl.messages
    var filename: String
    var index = 0

    for (messages in mess) {
        if (messages is TLMessage) {

            val b: TLAbsMessageMedia? = messages.media

            index++
            when (b) {
                is TLMessageMediaPhoto -> {
                    messageText = b.caption
                    filename = "photo$index.jpg"
                    println(messageText)
                    var ROOT_DIR = "C:\\fopii"
                    fos = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        FileOutputStream(File(ROOT_DIR, filename))
                    }
                    Input.add(b.getMediaInput()!!.inputFileLocation)
                    size.add(b.getMediaInput()!!.size)
                    // downloadSync closes the stream automatically
                }

                is TLMessageMediaDocument -> {
                    messageText = b.caption

                    val tlDocumentt = b.document.asDocument
                    val p = (tlDocumentt.attributes.stream()
                        .filter { attr: TLAbsDocumentAttribute? -> attr is TLDocumentAttributeFilename }
                        .findFirst().get() as TLDocumentAttributeFilename).fileName
                    filename = p
                    Input.add(b.getMediaInput()!!.inputFileLocation)
                    size.add(b.getMediaInput()!!.size)
                    var ROOT_DIR = "C:\\fopii"
                    fos = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                        FileOutputStream(File(ROOT_DIR, filename))
                    }

                }
            }

        }


        println(Input)
        println("$size a")
        println(messageText)
        client.downloadSync(Input.get(0), size.get(0), fos)



    }

}catch (e: Exception){
    e.printStackTrace()
}finally {
    client.close()
}
```

I get only 1 latest media file, but I need everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use

```
val tl = client.messagesGetHistory(inputPeer, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
```

If you look at the parameters for `getHistory`
in the [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.getHistory) you set a limit of 1.

Try to increase the number to 10 or 20.

I don't know how many files you want to grab. But you need a pagination or an infinity scrolling. I can not imagine that it is allowed to set the limit > 100

Comment: i changed it to 5 and got 5 times the last file in the post

Comment: i need to get media files from last post only

Comment: Yes, please read the telegram documentation the right way. 

```messages contains the last message sent to each conversation like you see in your list of conversations in your Telegram app```

So in every chat you got the last message. But telegram does not call it "chat". So if you have a conversation with A and B. If you use messages.getHistory(...,2,..)  you get the last message from conversation A and B

Have a look here: https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-the-telegram-api-b0cd220dbed2

So you're code it's wrong (my solution too). You need another API endpoint

Comment: I did it, your hint helped me, it turned out that I was here "client.downloadSync(Input.get(0), size.get(0), fos)" constantly took only the first file